# Attempting Simple String Output—Receiving Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort

I am attempting a mergesort algorithm and when I go to output some text, it ends up screwed. Here's my code:

```python
def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

def mergesort(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    middle = int(len(lst) / 2)
    left = mergesort(lst[:middle])
    right = mergesort(lst[middle:])
    return merge(left, right)

a = [3,1,2,5,9,6,7]
print 'Input #1: ' + str(a)
print 'Output #1: ' + mergesort(a)
```

And I am receiving this syntax error:

```
File "Lab1.py", line 21
  print 'Input #1: ' + str(a)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using **Python 3.3.2**.

Comment: `print()` is a function in py3.x

Comment: The windows console lets you copy text too, no need to make that screenshot. Click on the window menu top left, select 'Mark', mark the text, then select 'Copy' (or press Enter).

Comment: I know; Quick Edit mode. I just felt like retaining the cool Matrix-y feel to my console. Heh.